Generating iOS Build and Automatic Upload on TestFlight via Bitbucket Pipeline
We are utilizing Flutter Bitbucket Pipeline for our build development process. While the Android build is functioning correctly, we are encountering challenges with generating an iOS build and automatically uploading it to TestFlight for testing purposes.
How to achieve this within the Bitbucket Pipeline environment?

How far have you gotten?

What exact challenges did you encounter?

u can use Xcode cloud , it helped me alot check this documentation from flutter  :

https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/cd

